# Search ONLY in the news module in Contao CMS 2.11

Tags: search, contao

Short question - is it possible to add an (additional) search bar, with only the News being searched?

The part should be independent of the "global" search. I hope I have made myself clear.

I would like to offer a search something like this:

Search only in the news. 
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set one (or multiple) reference pages in your search result module. The search module will then only display search results from these pages. So if you set the reference page to your news detail page for example, you'll only see search results from the news.

**Note:** this applies to the most recent Contao versions. I am not sure if this feature is already present in Contao 2.11. Regardless of that, it is important that you immediately update your Contao installation to the most recent version (currently Contao 4.4 for LTS or Contao 4.7 for the newest features).

Comment: Thanks,  Yeah, Contao 2.11 also has the option to set the reference page.